# Override just the default scope (specifically order) and nothing else in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, default-scope

So basically I have two classes, **Book** and **Author**. Books can have multiple authors and authors can have multiple books. Books have the following default scope.

```
default_scope :order => "publish_at DESC"
```

On the Author show page I want to list all the books associated with that author so I say the following...

```
@author = Author.find(params[:id])
@books = @author.books
```

All is good so far. The author#show page lists all books belonging to that author ordered by publication date.

I'm also working on a gem that is able to sort by the popularity of a book.

```
@books = @author.books.sort_by_popularity
```

The problem is that whenever it tries to sort, the default_scope always gets in the way. And if I try to unscope it before it will get rid of the author relation and return every book in the database. For example

```
@books = @author.books.unscoped.sort_by_popularity # returns all books in database
```

I'm wondering if I can use the [ActiveRelation except() method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-except)
to do something like this (which seems like it should work but it doesn't. It ignores order, just not when it is a default_scope order)

```
def sort_by_popularity
  self.except(:order).do_some_joining_magic.order('popularity ASC')
  #    |------------|                       |---------------------|
end
```

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work? Any ideas on how to get this to work a different way? I  know I can just get rid of the default_scope but I'm wondering if there another way to do this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be able to use [`reorder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) to completely replace the existing ORDER BY:

> **reorder(*args)**
>   Replaces any existing order defined on the relation with the specified order.

So something like this:

```
def self.sort_by_popularity
  scoped.do_some_joining_magic.reorder('popularity ASC')
end
```

And I think you want to use a class method for that and `scoped` instead of `self` but I don't know the whole context so maybe I'm wrong.

I don't know why `except` doesn't work. The `default_scope` seems to get applied at the end (sort of) rather than the beginning but I haven't looked into it that much.

Comment: Thank you! That was so easy. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Agreed, this was a lifesaver. Never heard of reorder until now.

Comment: Allow me to third! I changed the order to a reorder in my named scope and it worked like a charm.

Comment: To completely remove `ORDER BY` clause from the query, pass `nil` to `reorder`: `<something>.reorder(nil).<something>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without losing `default_scope` or other ordering

```
@books.order_values.prepend 'popularity ASC'
```